# How do I align symbols in Latex equations?

Tags: latex

My equation

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eq}
    \hat{C_{text}} = \frac{A_{text}}{B_{text}}\bigg\rvert_{A_{text} = 1,\, B_{text} = 1}
\end{equation}
```

Gives me this

[image]

But I want

[image]

- Hat aligned
- Text on rigth side of \rvert stacked

How do I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Never use math mode for multi-letter words like `text`, this will mess up the kerning. `amsmath` has the `\text{...}` macro for such situations
- The hat is not centred because you wrapped it both around the `C` and its subscript. if you place it only around the `C` it will be centred
- one possibility to out the two conditions above each other could be `\substack{...\\...}`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:eq}
    \hat{C}_{\text{text}} = \frac{A_{\text{text}}}{B_{\text{text}}}\bigg\rvert_{\substack{A_{\text{text}} = 1 \\ B_{\text{text}} = 1}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]